# Chef undefined method `use_etag' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

When I run my cookbook on a node I get a compile error: "undefined method `use_etag' for Chef::Resource::RemoteFile" on my remote_file resource:

```
remote_file to.deb do
  mode                0644
  source              'https://path.com/to.deb'
  use_etag            true
  use_conditional_get true
end
```

According to Chef doc, use_etag is a attribute of remote_file.

Comment: What Chef version are you using? One older than 11.6.0? `use_etag` was introduced with Chef 11.6.0 (see [Release Notes](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Release+Notes))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use_etag` was not introduced until later versions of Chef (11.6.0 if I recall correctly). You may need to upgrade your Chef version.